# error: waitpid for C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe failed: No child processes

Tags: git, ssh, amazon-ec2, plink, aws-codecommit

[image]
[image]

I am trying to connect to a Codecommit server. I get the error below. Connection is from a Windows server. I do not get the error when I try will other similar machines. This was working fine at the start but developed this issue unexpectedly.

```
C:\chalaka>git clone -b development ssh://***************@git-codecommit.us
-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/AgileReady
Cloning into 'AgileReady'...
remote: Counting objects: 332, done.
Receiving objects: 100% (332/332), 1.77 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
remote:
Resolving deltas: 100% (84/84), done.
error: waitpid for C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe failed: No child processes
```

Checking connectivity... done.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem with git, using plink as ssh transport! The weird thing is that the actual transport works, but you have to sometimes execute the command twice. It's very flakey and I suspect it's a bug in the git wrapping scripts.

Comment: I get the same error, and I'm using Git Bash instead of Windows command prompt

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is caused by process ACL restrictions which were added to development snapshots of Plink as of 2016-04-03.

These have been removed from newer development snapshots as of 2017-01-30 (and were not included in any release version of Plink), so you should find that the problem goes away if you switch to a version newer than that.

Full details of the issue are at http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/win-process-acl-finesse.html

Answer (score 1):

I have the same conditions as in [this bug report](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/39792424-waitpid-for-plink-exe-fails-for-no-child-processes), and in it they say that this occurs for developmental versions of the PuTTY package. I haven't tested it, but seeing as I have no troubles with my other machine which uses a stable release, I'd have a guess that the developmental release is causing this error. They also note that the pushes and pulls are still doing everything correctly, just returning a non-successful exit.

Also, to note, I've had to manually add the environment variable

```
GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe
```

in Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Advanced > Environment Variables... (yes, the 64-bit developmental version of PuTTY)